# change key in OrderedDict without losing order

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

Starting with

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)])
```

is it possible to end up with

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('__C__', 3), ('b', 2)])
```

making sure that the `'__C__'` item is before `'b'` and after `'a'` i.e. keeping order?

Comment: You need to either create a new OrderedDict or use `move_to_end` method on each item after `c`

Comment: You can't do it efficiently like you could for a `list`. If the dictionarys are big and you need to be doing this, possibly `OrderedDict` is not the best choice of datastructure

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could try:

```
>>> d = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)])
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)])
>>> d2 = OrderedDict([('__C__', v) if k == 'c' else (k, v) for k, v in d.items()])
>>> d2
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('__C__', 3), ('b', 2)])
```

Comment: Why not: `d2 = OrdededDict([('__C__' if k == 'c' else k, v) for k, v in d.items()])` ?

Comment: Iterating over all items() just to change the key?

Answer (score 11):

if you wish to mutate the current dictionary object:

```
def change_key(self, old, new):
    for _ in range(len(self)):
        k, v = self.popitem(False)
        self[new if old == k else k] = v
```

This works by iterating over the whole `OrderedDict` (using its length), and [pop'ing its first item](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (by passing `False` to `.popitem()`: the default of this method is to pop the last item) into `k` and `v` (respectively standing for *key* and *value*); and then inserting this key/value pair, or the new key with its original value, at the end of the `OrderedDict`.

By repeating this logic for the entire size of the dict, it effectively rotates the dict completely, thus recreating the original order.

Comment: Same as above, but longer

Comment: @TahaJahangir not exactly, this answer does not create a new dict. This can sometimes be desired and sometimes undesired.

Comment: The reason this (completely different) approach is valuable is that it updates the original dictionary reference passed into a function, so changes will affect the outer scope. None of the other solutions given can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied with the dictionary needing reconstruction (at least partially), obviously for efficiency reasons, so I've put together a class that extends OrderedDict and allows you to do key changes efficiently.

It uses 2 extra dictionaries to remap the changed keys ("external" - i.e. as they appear externally to the user) to the ones in the underlying OrderedDict ("internal").

Please comment if you see issues or have improvements to propose as this might still be error-prone.

Here it is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class OrderedDictX(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._keys_ext2int = OrderedDict()
        self._keys_int2ext = OrderedDict()
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def change_key(self, k_old, k_new):
        # Validate that the old key is part of the dict
        if not self.__contains__(k_old):
            raise Exception(f'Cannot rename key {k_old} to {k_new}: {k_old} not existing in dict')

        # Return if no changing is actually to be done
        if len(OrderedDict.fromkeys([k_old, k_new])) == 1:
            return

        # Validate that the new key would not conflict with another one
        if self.__contains__(k_new):
            raise Exception(f'Cannot rename key {k_old} to {k_new}: {k_new} already in dict')

        # Change the key using internal dicts mechanism
        if k_old in self._keys_ext2int:
            # Revert change temporarily
            k_old_int = self._keys_ext2int[k_old]
            del self._keys_ext2int[k_old]
            k_old = k_old_int
            # Check if new key matches the internal key
            if len(OrderedDict.fromkeys([k_old, k_new])) == 1:
                del self._keys_int2ext[k_old]
                return

        # Finalize key change
        self._keys_ext2int[k_new] = k_old
        self._keys_int2ext[k_old] = k_new

    def __contains__(self, k) -> bool:
        if k in self._keys_ext2int:
            return True
        if not super().__contains__(k):
            return False
        return k not in self._keys_int2ext

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if not self.__contains__(k):
            # Intentionally raise KeyError in ext2int
            return self._keys_ext2int[k]
        return super().__getitem__(self._keys_ext2int.get(k, k))

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if k in self._keys_ext2int:
            return super().__setitem__(self._keys_ext2int[k], v)
        # If the key exists in the internal state but was renamed to a k_ext,
        # employ this trick: make it such that it appears as if k_ext has also been renamed to k
        if k in self._keys_int2ext:
            k_ext = self._keys_int2ext[k]
            self._keys_ext2int[k] = k_ext
            k = k_ext
        return super().__setitem__(k, v)

    def __delitem__(self, k):
        if not self.__contains__(k):
            # Intentionally raise KeyError in ext2int
            del self._keys_ext2int[k]
        if k in self._keys_ext2int:
            k_int = self._keys_ext2int[k]
            del self._keys_ext2int[k]
            del self._keys_int2ext[k_int]
            k = k_int
        return super().__delitem__(k)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.keys()

    def __reversed__(self):
        for k in reversed(super().keys()):
            yield self._keys_int2ext.get(k, k)

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, OrderedDictX):
            return False
        if len(self) != len(other):
            return False
        for (k, v), (k_other, v_other) in zip(self.items(), other.items()):
            if k != k_other or v != v_other:
                return False
        return True

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in OrderedDict(*args, **kwargs).items():
            self.__setitem__(k, v)

    def popitem(self, last=True) -> tuple:
        if not last:
            k = next(iter(self.keys()))
        else:
            k = next(iter(reversed(self.keys())))
        v = self.__getitem__(k)
        self.__delitem__(k)
        return k, v

    class OrderedDictXKeysView:
        def __init__(self, odx: 'OrderedDictX', orig_keys):
            self._odx = odx
            self._orig_keys = orig_keys

        def __iter__(self):
            for k in self._orig_keys:
                yield self._odx._keys_int2ext.get(k, k)

        def __reversed__(self):
            for k in reversed(self._orig_keys):
                yield self._odx._keys_int2ext.get(k, k)

    class OrderedDictXItemsView:
        def __init__(self, odx: 'OrderedDictX', orig_items):
            self._odx = odx
            self._orig_items = orig_items

        def __iter__(self):
            for k, v in self._orig_items:
                yield self._odx._keys_int2ext.get(k, k), v

        def __reversed__(self):
            for k, v in reversed(self._orig_items):
                yield self._odx._keys_int2ext.get(k, k), v

    def keys(self):
        return self.OrderedDictXKeysView(self, super().keys())

    def items(self):
        return self.OrderedDictXItemsView(self, super().items())


# FIXME: move this to pytest
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MAX = 25
    items = [(i+1, i+1) for i in range(MAX)]
    keys = [i[0] for i in items]
    d = OrderedDictX(items)

    # keys() before change
    print(list(d.items()))
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    # __contains__ before change
    assert 1 in d
    # __getitem__ before change
    assert d[1] == 1
    # __setitem__ before change
    d[1] = 100
    assert d[1] == 100
    d[1] = 1
    assert d[1] == 1
    # __delitem__ before change
    assert MAX in d
    del d[MAX]
    assert MAX not in d
    d[MAX] = MAX
    assert MAX in d
    print('== Tests before key change finished ==')

    # change_key and __contains__
    assert MAX-1 in d
    assert MAX*2 not in d
    d.change_key(MAX-1, MAX*2)
    assert MAX-1 not in d
    assert MAX*2 in d
    # items() and keys()
    items[MAX-2] = (MAX*2, MAX-1)
    keys[MAX-2] = MAX*2
    assert list(d.items()) == items
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    print(list(d.items()))
    # __getitem__
    assert d[MAX*2] == MAX-1
    # __setitem__
    d[MAX*2] = MAX*3
    items[MAX-2] = (MAX*2, MAX*3)
    keys[MAX-2] = MAX*2
    assert list(d.items()) == items
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    # __delitem__
    del d[MAX]
    items = items[:-1]
    keys = keys[:-1]
    assert list(d.items()) == items
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    d[MAX] = MAX
    items.append((MAX, MAX))
    keys.append(MAX)
    # __iter__
    assert list(d) == keys
    # __reversed__
    print(list(reversed(d.items())))
    assert list(reversed(d)) == list(reversed(keys))
    assert list(reversed(d.keys())) == list(reversed(keys))
    assert list(reversed(d.items())) == list(reversed(items))
    # pop_item()
    assert d.popitem() == (MAX, MAX)
    assert d.popitem() == (MAX*2, MAX*3)
    items = items[:-2]
    keys = keys[:-2]
    assert list(d.items()) == items
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    # update()
    d.update({1: 1000, MAX-2: MAX*4})
    items[0] = (1, 1000)
    items[MAX-3] = (MAX-2, MAX*4)
    assert list(d.items()) == items
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    # move_to_end()
    d.move_to_end(1)
    items = items[1:] + [items[0]]
    keys = keys[1:] + [keys[0]]
    assert list(d.items()) == items
    assert list(d.keys()) == keys
    # __eq__
    d.change_key(1, 2000)
    other_d = OrderedDictX(d.items())
    assert d == other_d
    assert other_d == d
```