# How do I rename a key while preserving order in dictionaries (Python 3.7+)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary, with this value:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

I would like to rename the key `b` to `B`, without it losing its second place. In [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) and higher, dictionaries preserve insertion order, so the order of the keys can be counted on and might mean something. The end result I'm looking for is:

```
{"a": 1, "B": 2, "c": 3}
```

The obvious code would be to run:

```
>>> dictionary["B"] = dictionary.pop("b")
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'B': 2}
```

However, this doesn't preserve the order as desired.

Comment: So you want to modify the same dictionary?

Comment: @RaySteam Yes, preferably.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change key in OrderedDict without losing order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150872/change-key-in-ordereddict-without-losing-order)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco It does answer the `OrderedDict` part, but not the `dict` part. I guess I can edit my question to exclude the `OrderedDict` part.

Comment: May ask why you want to do that? Notice that the answers in the linked question have an insertion cost of O(n)

Comment: @RaySteam I'm modifying a JSON file, and I want pretty diffs, but please, please, please, answerers, don't answer the JSON part, I only want to know the answer to this specific question as I can see myself needing to know the answer in other situations as well.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I've edited my question to make no longer overlap with the other question that you linked to.

Comment: So an acceptable answer could be another type of data-structure?

Comment: @RaySteam No. I know how to use an OrderedDict and forloops and so forth to find a solution to the JSON problem. What I want to know is if there is an elegant way to rename a key in a dictionary while preserving order, as that would be more elegant than the solution that I'm using for the JSON problem.

Comment: Then this is a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: @RaySteam No, the linked question is about OrderedDict, not about dictionaries.

Comment: You can then convert `OrderedDict` object passing it into `dict(obj)`. Like: `myDict = dict(OrderedDict((newkey if k == oldkey else k, v) for k, v in myDict.items()))`

Comment: dicts retain insertions order now but they are still not a good choice of data structure if you want to insert/remove at particular indexes. So, either choose a different data structure or else accept an O(n) solution like re-building the whole dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution modifies the dictionary `d` in-place. If performance is not a concern, you could do the following:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
replacement = {"b": "B"}

for k, v in list(d.items()):
    d[replacement.get(k, k)] = d.pop(k)

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 1, 'B': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Notice that the above solution will work for any numbers of keys to be replaced. Also note that you need to iterate over a copy of `d.items()` (using `list(d.items())`), as you shouldn't iterate over a dictionary while modifying its keys.

Answer (score 6):

```
foo = {'c': 2, 'b': 4, 'J': 7}
foo = {key if key != 'b' else 'B': value for key, value in foo.items()}
foo
Out[7]: {'c': 2, 'B': 4, 'J': 7}
```

Comment: This creates a new dictionary, it does not modify the existing one in place.

Answer (score 2):

As a variant of the existing answers that also works for more than once replacement, you can define another dictionary showing which keys to replace with that other keys:

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> repl = {"b": "B"}
>>> {repl.get(k, k): d[k] for k in d}
{'a': 1, 'B': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Of course, this still creates a new dictionary instead of updating the existing one and thus needs O(n), but at least it does so just once for all keys that need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
dict2 = dict()

for key in dict1:
    if key == 'b':
        dict2[key.upper()] = dict1[key]
    else:
        dict2[key] = dict1[key]

dict1 = dict2 #if you want to have it in original dict
```

You can set whatever value you want in **if** statement

Comment: This creates a new dictionary, it does not modify the existing one in place