# Custome the display's field in django REST

Tags: django-rest-framework

I use Django REST and I would know if it is possible to customise the display of attributes in the json response.

Exemple :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

and my serializer :

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']
```

But instead to see {'name' : 'its value'}, I would see {'My customed model name' : 'its value'}.

Do you think that it's possible?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [to_representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer) method of the serializer to change the name of the field:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        # ret is an OrderedDict, so this will change the order of the result.
        ret['custom_name'] = ret.pop('name')
        return ret

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # if you want to write to the serializer using your custom name.
        data['name'] = data.pop('custom_name')
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Comment: If you don't want to lose the order of your data you can check this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150872/change-key-in-ordereddict-without-losing-order

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is using a `SerializerMethodField` (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_customed_model_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_my_customed_model_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Although if you want the field name to have spaces in it, this solution won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    other_name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['other_name']
```